# How to maximize mtu size for SunOS 5.10 Generic_147440-26 sun4v sparc sun4v

Tags: mtu

Despite installing and enabling the 10G fiber card, data copy or transfer is still happening on a 1G rate.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add units to your bandwidth rates.  There's quite a difference between GB and Gb.  In fact, 1GB/s is about the expected transfer rate for a 10Gb card.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised.

1. Increasing the MTU has to happen on all network devices in the segment, all switches, all NICs, etc.
2. Many file copy mechanisms are single-threaded, and as you don't say which one you're using, but I bet it's rsync or NFS, the performance is severely limited by the capability of a single thread to hammer away at 10Gbit.
3. Are you sure your values are in Gigabits/second, not Gigabytes/second, as there's a factor of 8 difference there..  Could be the cause of some confusion.
4. There's a *huge* load of options for configuring a 10Gbit NIC's drivers, TCP timestamping, offload, synchronous ACK, all of which can limit the performance of a 10Gbit NIC.

I know this is for Linux, and you're on SunOS, but have a read of this: http://landley.net/kdocs/ols/2009/ols2009-pages-169-184.pdf